# Tumblr importer

Tags: posts, import, tumblr

Is it possible to import tumblr post to wordpress WMS without automatic publication?
My wordpress site has a multi-account. And I'd like to be able to check post, modify if needed before online publication.
and Does someone know in what format tumblr posts are exported?
Thanks for your help !!!

Comment: In what format tumblr posts are exported? Is there any API? Please, add this info to the Question itself ([edit]), and if you are not sure, your own research is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, no.

The importer is an automated tool that grabs content already published in one place and republishes it in another.  If you were importing from WordPress to WordPress, then publication status would be imported as well.

However, the Tumblr importer uses the Tumblr API to grab everything on your account.  If the post is published on Tumblr, it will be imported as a published post on WordPress.  If it's saved as a draft, it will be imported as a draft.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

1. Setup another wordpress installation somewhere on the net (local PC might be good enough depends on if you have images to import and the requirements for tumblr API)
2. Import the tumblr to it.
3. Edit whatever needs to be edited, or set the posts as private
4. export only the posts from your "staging" installation and import to final destination.